# Speeding up list comprehension

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I'm trying to create a function that loops over array and creates new array. Usint timeit i found out that the slowest part is the looping over numpy array.
Since the arrays that I use as input tend to be long I want to speed up is as much as possible.

Is there way to make list comprehension looping faster?
I provide a function to recreate my issue:

```
def get_days(year, month):
    months=np.array([31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31])
    if month==2:
        if (year%4==0 and year%100!=0) or (year%400==0):
            return 29
    return months[month-1]
```

This array needs to yield better performance:

```
res=np.arange(20788, 20940)
np.array([np.min([x+datetime.fromtimestamp(20809*24*60*60).day-1, x+get_days(datetime.fromtimestamp(20809*24*60*60).year, datetime.fromtimestamp(20809*24*60*60).month)]) for x in res])
```

Comment: Note that *every* invocation of `get_days` will allocate a new `months` array. Move this outside of the `get_days` function. Also check if using a regular array instead of a numpy array for `months` makes a difference.

Comment: Yea it improved the loop speed by a bit. However I wonder if there is some kind of map, or apply function that can apply np.min simultaneously over the list.

Comment: calling `datetime.fromtimestamp` once instead of three times will also help.

Comment: There's no reason to use `numpy` if the only thing you do is index a list.

Comment: The biggest optimization you can make is to get rid of `get_days` and inline the code; calling a user-defined function in Python is relatively expensive.

Comment: @chepner other functions in my program needs the input to be in form of numpy array, but i dont think that is botttlenecking the function.

Comment: Building a `numpy` array is almost certainly the most expensive thing you do inside the function. But simply calling the function itself is also expensive.

Comment: Iterating on a list is faster than iterating on array.  Even doing `[... for i in arr.tolist()]` can helo,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using list comprehension with loops, used numpy functions and vectorize.

```
b = np.array([np.min([x+datetime.fromtimestamp(20809*24*60*60).day-1, 
                      x+get_days(datetime.fromtimestamp(20809*24*60*60).year,
                                 datetime.fromtimestamp(20809*24*60*60).month)]) 
             for x in res])

c = np.minimum(res+datetime.fromtimestamp(20809*24*60*60).day-1,
               res+get_days(datetime.fromtimestamp(20809*24*60*60).year,
                            datetime.fromtimestamp(20809*24*60*60).month))

b == c
```

Output:

```
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True])
```

## Timings

```
%timeit b = np.array([np.min([x+datetime.fromtimestamp(20809*24*60*60).day-1, x+get_days(datetime.fromtimestamp(20809*24*60*60).year, datetime.fromtimestamp(20809*24*60*60).month)]) for x in res])
```

> 1.99 ms ± 33.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

```
%timeit c = np.minimum(res+datetime.fromtimestamp(20809*24*60*60).day-1, res+get_days(datetime.fromtimestamp(20809*24*60*60).year, datetime.fromtimestamp(20809*24*60*60).month))
```

> 10.5 µs ± 310 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

Answer (score 0):

as @botje commented. notice that you have some vars that will be allocated whenever you call that function inside the list comprehension. I managed to make it faster when I declare those vars outside the function. my code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from helpers.time_dec import calc_execution_time

months=np.array([31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31])
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(20809 * 24 * 60 * 60)
dt_day = dt.day

def get_days(year, month):

    if month==2:
        if (year%4==0 and year%100!=0) or (year%400==0):
            return 29
    return months[month-1]

d =  get_days(dt.year, dt.month)


@calc_execution_time
def calc():
    res = np.arange(20788, 20940)

    r = np.array([np.min([x + dt_day - 1,
                      x +d]) for x in res])
    return r


print(calc()) # 0.0011 seconds, and your code showed 0.0026 seconds. So obviously the Performance is better now

################### this is the test exectution time function ###############
from timeit import default_timer



def calc_execution_time(func):

    """calculate execution Time of a function"""



    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        before = default_timer()
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        after = default_timer()
        execution_time = after - before
        print(f"execution time of the Function {func.__qualname__} is :=> {execution_time} seconds")
        return res

    return wrapper
```

you can also use the map function. I'm not what is your goal but I think you can change your function to use map instead of list comprehension and it will return a generator object, so the code will look like this:

```
@calc_execution_time
def calc():
    res = np.arange(20788, 20940)

    #r = np.array([np.min([x + dt_day - 1, x +d]) for x in res])

    r = map(lambda x: np.min([x + dt_day - 1, x +d]), res)
    return r


print(list(calc()))   # 1.65 e-05 seconds
```